# article - category schema across different parts of the app , united or divided ?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema, database-schema

I'm in need of help designing a schema for a custom CMS, with these tables:

- Products / Articles
- News
- Events

Every tables has got the usual stuff (only id's and non-text fields, the text ones are in multilanguages tables)...

My problem comes from the creation of a ___CATEGORY table, every main table has a category table related

should I create two separate table for every "master" table  (one for the category and one for the relations)

```
ProductCategory ( category_id ... )
ProductCategoryRel ( category_id , product_id )

NewsCategory ( category_id ... )
NewsCategoryRel ( category_id , news_id )

EventCategory ( category_id ... )
EventCategoryRel ( category_id , event_id )
```

Or should I create something united like this:

```
MainCategory ( category_id, type (Product/News/Event) ... )

ProductCategoryRel ( category_id , product_id )
NewsCategoryRel ( category_id , news_id )
EventCategoryRel ( category_id , event_id )
```

I really can't decide, both solutions aren't perfect...

Please note that the Products Category could have different (more) fields than the News/Events Category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "Please note that the Products Category could have different (more) fields than the News/Events Category" then you should definitely go for the first option.

See http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/ ("One ring to rule them all")

Comment: Nice Link ! he's right, it's probably going to take some work though...oh,well ! thanks !